# Settings and File Explorers apps won't open

Tags: windows-10

My machine was out of use for a while (a year or so) and when I booted it again, something weird happened: some apps refused to work. Like Settings and File Explorer. To be precise, what happens is that when I try to open them from the Start menu, they do show up on the task bar, and, weirdest of all, the thumbnail preview shows the little windows with contents one would expect. But, when I click on the icon to actually switch to the app window, nothing happens. Super annoying. Other apps work just fine (like Chrome, or the Windows Security app).

Tried several recommended 'fixes', like running sfc or dism to deal with potentially corrupted files. Downloaded and applied latest updates from Microsoft: nothing seems to work.

Comment: My machine was out of use for a while (a year or so)  .... Let updates complete, restart and see if there is still an issue.

Comment: Applied updates, restarted the machine, say ... 10 times already. To be precise, I went to https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10 and clicked on "Update now" to get "Windows 10 2022 Update l Version 22H2".

Comment: They are probably opening off the screen

Answer (score 1):

The damage is too extensive to be a simple glitch. I think you may need
to look for hardware problems in addition to software.

My suggestions :

- Search the Event Viewer for errors.
- Check the SMART attributes of the disk. If you don't have a product
  for that, use [speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy).
- Run `chkdsk` (not with the `/f` parameter)
- If nothing is found,
  [Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Answer (score 0):

First, since the machine has been off for a year, get the Manufacturer's Hardware Diagnostics app and test ALL hardware. Make sure you test the main disk.

It seems likely you have a hardware issue.

If (and only if) hardware seems to be OK, run a Windows 10 Repair Install.

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

There are 3 ways to proceed, according to the severity of the error.

(1) Keep Everything: Best if it works and your computer comes back just the way you had set it up except repaired.  Always have a backup, but generally nothing will be lost.

(2) Keep Data: Necessary if the operating system damage is extensive. Keeps the User Profile and makes software install quite easy. Always have a backup, but data is not usually lost.

(3) Keep Nothing: Deletes the User Profile and all else and is essentially a fresh install.  Be certain you have backed up all your data. "Keep Nothing" is necessary if the User Profile is damaged, because broken User Profiles cannot be repaired and it is generally easier to back up and start over if the User Profile is damaged. It depends on the precise situation.